# Intellije IDEA скачивает артифакты при билде каждый раз при запуске сервера Tomcat из IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

IDE перезакачивает артифакты каждый раз и после запуска mvn clean install и даже после запуска ранера в котором тоже уже закачивала эти артифакты.

После запуска `mvn clean install` я запускаю сервер Tomcat с Run Configuration Maven в IDE но вместо того чтобы запускать сервер он скачивает SNAPSHOT артифакты, которые уже скачивались при сборке мавеном. Остановлю сервер заново запускаю сервер, IDE заново скачивает теже самые артифакты, снова и снова при каждом перезапуске сервера.

Если поставить галочку `Work Offline` в настройках IDE, при запуске пишет

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ****.application.war: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.*****.application.war:war:251.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.*****.application.server:jar:251.0.0-SNAPSHOT, com.*****.common:jar:251.0.0-
```

Галочка `Always update snapshot` не установлена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете команду clean , которая удалит все ранее скомпилированные исходники и ресурсы Java  в вашем проекте. Ваша сборка начнется с чистого листа.

Comment: Думается вы ошиблись топиком

Comment: Тогда это произошло очень удачно, ведь вы поправили свой вопрос так, что он стал более понятным.

Comment: Даже для предыдущего варианта объяснение как работает clean не удачно)

Comment: Главное что сработало как надо ;)

Comment: Только понял, ну спасибо, сработало)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит потому что вы используете SNAPSHOT артифакты.

Maven сохраняет артифакты в кеш, только для релизных версий.

SNAPSHOT артифакты подразумевают, что они могут быть изменены автором, поэтому Maven вынужден отказаться от кеширования.

UPD:

Вам стоит попробовать ключ `-nsu`, который отключает обновления для SNAPSHOT зависимостей.

> `-nsu`,`--no-snapshot-updates`    Suppress SNAPSHOT updates

[Документация](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html)
[Ответ на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127142/9978153)

Comment: Почему галочка Always Update Snapshots не работает?

Comment: @JMas а Вы запускаете `mvn clean install` из консоли или через IDEA?

Comment: Из консоли bash в IDEA

Comment: @JMas я дополнил ответ, возможно это Вам поможет

Comment: Как я могу добавить это значение для build этапа, который запускается до основого Run Configuration

Comment: @JMas, я не знаю как добавить это для постоянного запуска. Для единоразового решения это помогло? Проект собрался без перезагрузки артифактов?

Comment: Завтра проверю отпишусь

Comment: Помогло, добавив -Dnsu в Run Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить настройку `Checksum polisy` на `No Global Policy`

[image: Maven Checksum Policy Setting]

Насколько мне известно, для SNAPSHOT зависимостей Maven производит проверку контрольной суммы, чтобы выяснить, требуется ли перезагрузить артифакт.

Comment: Поменяв Checksum policy на No Global Policy можно будет только избежать fail если checksum артифактов не совпадает.